Do the algebraic manipulations required in proofs eventually become natural through practice and exercise?
I have been recently reading Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and (reading the book's proof of the existence and uniqueness of n-th positive roots of positive reals, situated towards the end of the first chapter) was absolutely stunned by the command of algebraic manipulations that would be required to come up with such a proof.
I was stunned, as I said, and most of all frightened by the fact.
While the ideas behind the manipulations – that is, the "strategy" of the proof – were somewhat intuitive, their translation into a formal and axiomatic language (in this case of ordered fields) looked like effortless mastery, at least in my (inexperienced) eyes.
In your personal experience, does a similar kind of skill come natural through repeated exercise and practice with the algebraic structure in question? Or does in your opinion the author of the proof posses some kind of above-average command of the algebra involved which is not to be taken for granted?
(I, of course, understand that one does not simply speak a finished proof out of nowhere, but its concise formulation always naturally takes at least some kind of prolonged effort)
It is out of this fright of mine that was spawned this question, (hopefully) looking for some kind of reassurance.
P.S. I am new to asking on this website, so if you find that this kind of question does not quite belong to the purpose of StackExchange I make my apologies.

It looks effortless because it's the culmination of hundreds of years of inquiry and experience. In math once it's prove it's forever and those techniques remain for us to enjoy after the fact. Don't be afraid to struggle against a problem and fail. Every mathematician does that at times.

Like every skill, this is something you get better at the more you do it. The more you use a given axiomatic system, the more you get a feel for what each axiom "does" and get better at recognizing when and how to apply it.

A good way to deepen your understanding is to take a sort of reverse mathematics perspective of the proofs you encounter. That is, if axioms $A$ and $B$ are used to prove property $P$, can you find two example structures satisfying $A\land\lnot P$ and $B\land\lnot P$ respectively?

In the proofs In Rudin that you are looking at, I expect there are many common patterns. E.g., to show a function is "unique", i.e., one-to-one, then if the function is on an ordered domain, then a natural trick is to show it is strictly order-preserving. To extend a function known on the natural numbers to the reals, use algebra to extend to the integers and then the rationals and then use arguments involving infima or suprema or limits and continuity to extend it to the reals. It looks like conjuring at first, but when you practice you can learn to see the patterns behing the tricks.

@Karl I would not phrase things in terms of reverse mathematics, but instead say more plainly that students should ask themselves why each hypothesis in a theorem is there by trying to find a counterexample (not an "example structure") to the conclusion of the theorem if that hypothesis is removed.

@KCd: your comment reminds me that we should recommend Polya's wonderful book How to Solve it to the OP. The book is a delight to read and covers both problems "to solve" and problems "to prove" with lots of really informative exercises. The techniques discussed certainly include examining the relevance of hypotheses and looking for counter-examples when hypotheses are weakened.

Algebraic manipulations do get easier with practice. How many of us will ever reach Rudin's level of skill is another question, but also keep in mind that the proof you see in a book may have been revised and improved several times. You don't need to get the most beautiful concise proof the first time around.
